# Code for view changes for firestore snapshots

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I have gone thru the documentation of Firestore: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen?authuser=0

But while using same code, i am not able to resolve symbols such as DocumentChange, EventListener.
Similarly, I am not able to resolve methods such as getDocumentChanges, getDocument, addSnapshotListener.

I have already imported 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.8.0'.

build.gradle file

```
group 'firestore'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
apply plugin: 'java'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.8.0'
}
```

Here is the code, I am trying:

```
package firestore;

import com.google.api.core.SettableApiFuture;
import com.google.firestore.v1beta1.DocumentChange;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.DocumentChange;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.DocumentChange.Type;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.EventListener;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.ListenerRegistration;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.Firestore;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreException;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.Query;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.QuerySnapshot;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.annotation.Nullable;
import static com.google.api.ChangeType.ADDED;
import static com.google.api.ChangeType.MODIFIED;
import static com.google.api.ChangeType.REMOVED;

/**
 * Snippets to demonstrate Firestore 'listen' operations.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("Convert2Lambda")
public class FirestoreChange {
    private static final long TIMEOUT_SECONDS = 5;

    private final Firestore db;

    FirestoreChange(Firestore db) {
        this.db = db;
    }

    /**
     * Listen to a query, returning the list of DocumentChange events in the first snapshot.
     */
    List<DocumentChange> listenForChanges() throws Exception {
        SettableApiFuture<List<DocumentChange>> future = SettableApiFuture.create();

        // [START listen_for_changes]
        db.collection("cities")
                .whereEqualTo("state", "CA")
                .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot snapshots,
                                        @Nullable FirestoreException e) {
                        if (e != null) {
                            System.err.println("Listen failed: " + e);
                            return;
                        }

                        for (DocumentChange dc : snapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                            switch (dc.getType()) {
                                case ADDED:
                                    System.out.println("New city: " + dc.getDocument().getData());
                                    break;
                                case MODIFIED:
                                    System.out.println("Modified city: " + dc.getDocument().getData());
                                    break;
                                case REMOVED:
                                    System.out.println("Removed city: " + dc.getDocument().getData());
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
                        if (!future.isDone()) {
                            future.set(snapshots.getDocumentChanges());
                        }
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                });
        // [END listen_for_changes]

        return future.get(TIMEOUT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please provide the a [mcv](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including your class and your build.gradle file.

Comment: @AlexMamo, Graddle File :-       


    group 'firestore'

    version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'


apply plugin: 'java'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.8.0'
}

Comment: Code is of the section of 'View changes between snapshots' from the URL: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen?authuser=0

Comment: Please edit your question, by adding the mcv and the build.gradle file.

Comment: @AlexMamo, I have updated the code, can you please review and let me know what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you didn't add Cloud Firestore dependencies in build.gradle file at all. Adding `firebase-admin` is not enought to make Firestore work. So to solve this, just add this line of code:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'
```

Right after the `firebase-admin` dependencies. Sync your project and try again.

Comment: I updated BuildGraddle file, but still didn't work out to resolve the imports.

Comment: Try to clean your project and rebuild it again.